# How to launch app in landscape? (frustrated)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, landscape, uiinterfaceorientation

this issue is supposed to be a simple one...
i have googled a lot about it and i have tried all the setups on my project. 
the thing is i am working on a project that is not mine. the app launched from the app delegate and then i am adding a`UIViewController` (without XIB file) everything done by code.
the ViewController is actually on landscape, but the thing is the the app is running on portrait (when i am pulling the notification view it turns dow like in the portrait mode).

this is implemented in the AppDelegate.m file:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
 }



- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{                                                                                                     

 return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; 

 //if i am writing only the landscape right orientation the app crashes!



}
```

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3bfef2a3 0x35ede97f 0x3bfef1c5 0x3518988f 0x3532e579 0x3520dd3d 0x3520cfc7 0x3532f257 0xa5bc1 0x35188319 0x351a4f0f 0x351a4e97 0x3512aa33 0x3bfc46cd 0x3bfc29c1 0x3bfc2d17 0x3bf35ebd 0x3bf35d49 0x3a3032eb 0x351752f9 0x9803b 0x97fe0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

if i am writing it with the portrait mode the app launches. i have also tried to add row in the `info.plist` and set the key to initial interface orientation value to the landscape (right home button).
also put the supported interface orientation to lanscape as well.
non of this change anything, i just want to know how i can get that behavior to get the notification from above in the landscape mode

Anyone, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Try this way in your app delegate .m file ...**

```
    #define IOS_OLDER_THAN_6 ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] systemVersion ] floatValue ] < 6.0 )
    #define IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6 ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] systemVersion ] floatValue ] >= 6.0 )



        - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
        {


            self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1]; // simulate waiting for server response

            // Override point for customization after application launch.

            self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

            // Initialise the navigation controller with the first view controller as its root view controller

            UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

            // This is where we hide the navigation bar! :)

            [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

            // Navigation controller has copy of view controller, so release our copy


               [self.viewController release];

            // Add the navigation controller as a subview of our window

            if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] < 6.0)
            {
                // how the view was configured before IOS6
                [self.window addSubview: navigationController.view];
               // [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
            }
            else
            {
                // this is the code that will start the interface to rotate once again
        //        [self.window setRootViewController: self.navigationController];
                [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
            }

        //    [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
            [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
            return YES;
        }


    #ifdef IOS_OLDER_THAN_6
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
       // [image_signature setImage:[self resizeImage:image_signature.image]];
        return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    }
    #endif

    #ifdef IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6
    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
        return YES;
    }
    - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
       // [image_signature setImage:[self resizeImage:image_signature.image]];
        //return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    }
    #endif

    - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    }
```

**`

> And also Write down the this code in your all view controller .m file

`**

```
#define IOS_OLDER_THAN_6 ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] systemVersion ] floatValue ] < 6.0 )
#define IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6 ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] systemVersion ] floatValue ] >= 6.0 )


#ifdef IOS_OLDER_THAN_6
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
   // [image_signature setImage:[self resizeImage:image_signature.image]];
    //return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    if(toInterfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
        NSLog(@"Changed Orientation To Landscape left");

        return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);

    }else{
        NSLog(@"Changed Orientation To Landscape right");
        return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    }
}
#endif

#ifdef IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
  //  [image_signature setImage:[self resizeImage:image_signature.image]];
    //return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
#endif
```

Comment: first of all thanks for the quick response, but i am not using a UINavigation controller

Comment: it wont crash only if i add "UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait" to the supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow method

Comment: ok try this code...- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight |UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

Comment: the app is not crash but the notification screen is coming like in portrait mode

Comment: i found out that the problem is happen when i am setting the root view controller for the app window! if i am cancelling that line the app opens in landscape mode... as it seems i need to change the window orientation (that is locked)