# Application is crashed due to InterfaceOrientation

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiinterfaceorientation

My application is `Landscape` based. The app crashes immediately when the app runs on my device.

I have selected these two fields

```
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
```

I am getting this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation,  reason: Supported
>   orientations has no common orientation with the application, and
>   shouldAutorotate is returning YES

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911080/how-to-launch-app-in-landscape-frustrated/13911169#13911169

Comment: are you using image picker in that view ? Did you set it as the rootview ?

Comment: Have you set any supported interface orientation in the summary of the project.

Answer (score 2):

Add **shouldAutorotate** and **supportedInterfaceOrientations** methods to your controller.

```
 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {
        return YES; //this will auto-rotate the orientation.
    }



-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape; // will force the app to load in landscape, you can change it as per your need.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation return only those with you want to support

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
```

please check one more thing, the connection between the `File's Owner and View`, if the view will not attach with the file's Owner It will crash.

Answer (score 0):

You should use UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape instead of UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft & UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight. In iOS SDK 6.0+, new enum(UIInterfaceOrientationMask) is used for returning supported orientations.