# How to autorotate UIView based on device orientation iOS 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios6, orientation

I have started my project with iOS 5.0, Now updated to iOS 6, I am facing problem in doing orientation, To test I have created a sample application, and added the following code in delegate...

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

And in my view controller I have implemented the following methods...

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

All the above I have done after googled about iOS 6.0,when I load application, based on the option given in supportedInterfaceOrientations view is loading that is fine, now when I changes my device orientations... view is not changing accordingly at run time, how do I change my view based on the device orientation?

```
NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[notificationCenter addObserver:self
                       selector:@selector(deviceOrientationDidChange) 
                           name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Do I need to add observer like above and changes it programmatically? or Will the view change automatically by detecting device orientation?

Comment: refere this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100233/application-is-crashed-due-to-interfaceorientation/14100730#14100730

Comment: If you use UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape you will only have that view on landscape

Comment: @jcesar then how do I change at run time?

Comment: @Prince Ya I agree, he is right, when loading a view that is deciding, after loading when device orientation changes,.. how to rotate automatically.. that I don't know..

Comment: Then, you want the view to be on landscape when it appears, and then rotate if necessary?

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}


- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}


- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape;
}
```

The previous code should work on iOS6

Anyways, I use this code on one of my projects. I have a boolean `_firstTime`, and I set it to `YES` before showing the `viewController`, then I change it to `NO` after the `viewController` appears

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if (_firstTime) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }

}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {

        return YES;

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (_firstTime) {
        return return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)||(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: check the last update, I use it to remove the rotation while I show a video and it works

Comment: Yes, but your problem might be the UINavigationController, you should create a subclass of navigationController and put this code there. Then, create a custom navigation controllers instead the regular one

Comment: I have created sample (single view) application only, in which I have not used navigation controller self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; I have loaded like this.. ViewController view also not rotating,

  Any idea?

Comment: can you upload the sample project somewhere?

Comment: iPad killed my time from morning I think, problem is with iPad, I tried with iPod now, working charm... Oh..god :)

Answer (score 1):

Change in these method:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

**Note** : No need to add `observer` for `device notification`.Given below method will specify orientation status

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
```

**EDIT** : Provide all your `views` will `automasking` according to `requirement`

**EDIT** : If using `UINavigation Controller` then its `child View Controller's` `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `shouldAutorotate` method will not be `called`.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12539784/1106035) link.

Comment: Still view is not rotating at run time.

Comment: willRotateToInterfaceOrientation itself not getting called in my case? Any idea? what am doing wrong?

Comment: I did already... all are selected... Before in iOS 5.0 no problem.. But in iOS 6.0 this is not working. And I'm using iPad is it matters?

Comment: are u using UINavigation Controller?

Comment: Ya...         self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    
    UINavigationController *navigationcontroller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationcontroller;
    
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; ANYTHING WRONG IN THIS?

Comment: that's issue here. Check edited answer.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520030/how-to-force-a-uiviewcontroller-to-portait-orientation-in-ios-6

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with my iPad. it has a button to restrict auto rotation change... I was not aware initially, as I was worked fully with iPod.. Thanks all for your helps.